# Deploying react app to a webpage shows blank screen

Tags: html, reactjs, browser

I'm trying to implement a react app to my webpage but it keeps displaying blank screen. I run "npm run-script build" and the build is fine, running npm start displays the component properly on localhost but when trying to display in the webpage the browser is blank with no errors in console. Path is correct and "homepage" is added in the package.json

Any suggestions appreciated

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what the issue you're facing is however based on what you've provided it seems like what you need is to use `npm run build`?